# How to do filtering in 'Call to Test' dialog in HP ALM?

Tags: test-design, quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

After pressing `Call to Test` button `Select a Test` dialog window opens.

[image: Filtering on Select a Test window]

How to make filtering down to the desired folder (e.g. containing on different levels "03." & "Templates") so to save time while using these templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to filter by 'Subject' and not by 'Path'

[image: filtering conditions]

After that there is only desired path displayed in `Call to Test` dialog.